# Не выполняется gulpfile.babel.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, babel

1. Клонировал https://github.com/google/material-design-lite
2. Установил все зависимости командой `npm install`
3. Собираю проект командой `gulp`

Но получаю такой ответ:

```html
[07:30:45] Failed to load external module babel-register
[07:30:45] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[07:30:52] Using gulpfile D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\gulpfile.babel.js
[07:30:52] Starting 'clean'...
[07:30:52] Finished 'clean' after 16 ms
[07:30:52] Starting 'default'...
[07:30:52] Starting 'styles'...
[07:30:53] Starting 'styles-grid'...
[07:30:55] styles-grid all files 18.82 kB
[07:30:55] Finished 'styles-grid' after 1.52 s
[07:30:57] styles all files 853.19 kB
[07:30:57] Finished 'styles' after 4.22 s
[07:30:57] Starting 'lint'...
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\mdlComponentHandler.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |/**
    18 | * A component handler interface using the revealing module design pattern.


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\animation\demo.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |/**
    18 | * Class constructor for Animation MDL component.


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\button\button.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\checkbox\checkbox.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\data-table\data-table.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\icon-toggle\icon-toggle.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\layout\layout.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\menu\menu.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\progress\progress.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\radio\radio.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\ripple\ripple.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\slider\slider.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\snackbar\snackbar.js :
    13 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    14 | * limitations under the License.
    15 | */
-----------^
    16 |(function() {
    17 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\spinner\spinner.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\switch\switch.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\tabs\tabs.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\textfield\textfield.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\third_party\rAF.js :
     1 |// Source: https://github.com/darius/requestAnimationFrame/blob/master/requestAnimationFrame.js
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
     2 |// Adapted from https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671 which derived from
     3 |// http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\tooltip\tooltip.js :
    14 | * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    15 | * limitations under the License.
    16 | */
-----------^
    17 |(function() {
    18 |  'use strict';


1 code style error found.
validateLineBreaks: Invalid line break at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\gulpfile.babel.js :
    16 | *  limitations under the License
    17 | *
    18 | */
-----------^
    19 |
    20 |// jscs:disable jsDoc


1 code style error found.
[07:31:00] 'lint' errored after 3.78 s
[07:31:00] Error in plugin 'gulp-jscs'
Message:
    JSCS failed for: D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\mdlComponentHandler.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\animation\demo.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\button\button.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\checkbox\checkbox.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\data-table\data-table.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\icon-toggle\icon-toggle.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\layout\layout.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\menu\menu.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\progress\progress.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\radio\radio.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\ripple\ripple.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\slider\slider.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\snackbar\snackbar.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\spinner\spinner.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\switch\switch.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\tabs\tabs.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\textfield\textfield.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\third_party\rAF.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\tooltip\tooltip.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\gulpfile.babel.js
[07:31:00] 'default' errored after 8.05 s
[07:31:00] Error in plugin 'run-sequence(lint)'
Message:
    JSCS failed for: D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\mdlComponentHandler.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\animation\demo.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\button\button.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\checkbox\checkbox.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\data-table\data-table.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\icon-toggle\icon-toggle.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\layout\layout.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\menu\menu.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\progress\progress.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\radio\radio.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\ripple\ripple.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\slider\slider.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\snackbar\snackbar.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\spinner\spinner.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\switch\switch.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\tabs\tabs.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\textfield\textfield.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\third_party\rAF.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\src\tooltip\tooltip.js, D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\gulpfile.babel.js
Stack:
    at finish (D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:56:13)
    at Gulp.onError (D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\node_modules\run-sequence\index.js:67:4)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:52:4)
    at DestroyableTransform.f (D:\cms\admin\vendor\material-design-lite\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\node_modules\end-of-stream\node_modules\once\once.js:17:25)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
```

С babel первый раз работаю, поэтому думал что нет соответствующих зависимостей, проверил `node_modules` в ней есть `babel-core` и `babel-present-es2015`.

Подскажите, в чем дело?

Comment: Иван, ниже написал возможное решение — попробуйте. Если не решит проблемы — пишите, какие ошибки ещё возникают. Важно также чтобы при установке зависимостей поставились правильно все пакеты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в окончании строк, потому что вы работаете в Windows. Когда вы выполняете `gulp` происходит линтинг JavaScript файлов, то есть поиск ошибок и проверка на соответствие файлов стандартам оформления кода.

**После того как клонируете репозираций используя Git**

```sh
git clone https://github.com/google/material-design-lite.git
```

**В директории с проектом нужно запустить команды**

> Пользователи Windows, если у вас возникли проблемы с компиляцией из-за окончания строки, убедитесь, что вы настроили git для проверки репозитория с окончанием строки `lf` (unix). Этого можно добиться, установив `core.eol`.

```sh
git config core.eol lf
git config core.autocrlf input
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

Инструкции по этому также есть в самом репозитории — [Download / Clone](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite#download--clone).

---

#### Клонирование и установка зависимостей

Если после клонирования репозитория, во время установки зависимостей `npm install` возникают ошибки, например, из-за медленного интернет соединения какие-то пакеты полностью не скачались должным образом — в большинстве случаев достаточно повторно запустить эту команду (может даже несколько раз).